# Stop the tag builder escaping single quotes ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following `HtmlHelper` method that I want to create a button that does a redirect with JavaScript:

```
public static string JavaScriptButton(this HtmlHelper helper, string value,
                        string action, string controller, object routeValues = null, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var a = (new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext))
                            .Action(action, controller, routeValues);

    var builder = new TagBuilder("input");
    builder.Attributes.Add("type", "submit");
    builder.Attributes.Add("value", value);
    builder.Attributes.Add("class", "button");
    builder.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("javascript:location.href='{0}'", a));
    builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing)).ToString();         
}
```

The problem is that the line that creates the onclick handler is getting escaped by the tagbuilder, the resulting html is:

```
<input class="button" onclick="javascript:location.href=&#39;&#39;" type="submit" value="Return to All Audits" />
```

Is there anyway I can stop this behaviour?

Comment: Can't you simply use a link (`<a href=...>`)? I've always wondered why people would clutter their HTML with javascript and use a form submit button, to perform a redirect when there's the anchor element designed for this purpose.

Comment: Probably because he wants the visual style of a button? However he should be using `type=button` instead of submit.

Comment: you are right, it should be using of type button and I do want a visual button.  I did create another button which created uses the tagbuilder to wrap a form around a submit but I got into problems with styling issues and nested forms within forms which is why I went this route.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is actually an issue with .NET 4.0.  To fix it you need to override the attribute encoding process.

```
public class HtmlAttributeNoEncoding : System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder
{
    protected override void HtmlAttributeEncode(string value, System.IO.TextWriter output)
    {
        output.Write(value);
    }
}
```

Then put this in your web.config file under the `<system.web>` element:

```
<httpRuntime encoderType="HtmlAttributeNoEncoding"/>
```

I found this [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1554455/3818604.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

While the solution provided by Ryan may work, it is a little like using a hammer to swat a fly.

The issue is that TagBuilder encodes strings during calls to MergeAttributes(). For the required Javascript in a button link this affects single quotes and spaces.

The last step of the required extension method is the return of an `MvcHtmlString` (which receives no further encoding), so it is perfectly reasonable to make some simple text corrections to the string (to undo the encoding) before creating that object.

### e.g.

```
return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal).Replace("&#39;", "\'").Replace("&#32;"," "));
```

### A complete ActionLinkButton helper is shown below:

```
public static class ActionLinkButtonHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkButton(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string buttonText, string actionName, object routeValuesObject = null, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        return ActionLinkButton(htmlHelper, buttonText, actionName, "", routeValuesObject, htmlAttributes);
    }
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkButton(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string buttonText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValuesObject = null, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName))
        {
            controllerName = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        }
        RouteValueDictionary routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValuesObject);
        RouteValueDictionary htmlAttr = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("button");
        tb.MergeAttributes(htmlAttr, false);
        string href = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl("default", actionName, controllerName, routeValues, RouteTable.Routes, htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, false);

        tb.MergeAttribute("type", "button");
        tb.SetInnerText(buttonText);
        tb.MergeAttribute("value", buttonText);
        tb.MergeAttribute("onclick", "location.href=\'"+ href +"\';return false;");
        return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal).Replace("&#39;", "\'").Replace("&#32;"," "));
    }
}
```

This does everything you need to add button links, has the most useful overloads you use with `ActionLink` and does not potentially cause unexpected application-wide changes by changing the attribute encoding process.

Answer (score 0):

The `TagBuilder` does not encode the string during `MergeAttribute` as directly manipulating the Attributes property and then getting the string representation with `ToString()` is also escaping the characters. Most probably the encoding happens during `ToString()`.

The class below solves the problem with JavaScript:

```
public class JavaScriptTagBuilder : TagBuilder
{
    public string OnClick { get; set; }

    public JavaScriptTagBuilder(string tagName)
        : base(tagName)
    {
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string openingTag = "<" + TagName;
        return base.ToString().Replace(openingTag, string.Format("{0} onclick=\"{1}\"", openingTag, OnClick));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the disco but you could decode the HTML before returning it:

```
return new MvcHtmlString(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
```