# Pass GridView column value to Javascript function - OnClientClick

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a grid view like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlPersistentOffenders" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GVPersistentOffenders" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlPersistentOffenders" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PersonID" Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="LabCreUser" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("creUser")%>'></asp:Label>                       
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonSendEmail" runat="server" CommandName="SendEmail" CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>" Text="Send Email" OnClientClick="GetEmailAddress()"/>                     
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The JavaScript looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function GetEmailAddress(creuser) {
           //Do something
}
</script>
```

How can I pass the value in LabCreUser for the row selected to the Javasript function?

I have looked here: [Passing variables to javascript in onclientclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850327/passing-variables-to-javascript-in-onclientclick) and also a few other questions.  Nothing I have tried has worked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass the parameter to the JS function this way

```
OnClientClick=<%# "GetEmailAddress('" + Eval("creUser") + "')" %>
```

this will became in

```
OnClientClick="GetEmailAddress('yourValue')"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `<asp:button>` with an HTML button, and use `onclick` to call your JavaScript function, and if you need a server side function add `runat="server"`