# ASP.Net C# Razor showing encoded HTML instead of raw html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, razor

I'm using the JQM-DateBox - which needs the following Razor markup:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.From, new { @name = "mydate", @id = "mydate",  
@data_role = "datebox", 
@data_options = "{'mode':'flipbox', 'dateFormat':'dd/mm/YYYY' ,'useNewStyle':true} ")
```

However, this renders as:

```
 <input data-options=" {&#39;mode&#39;:&#39;flipbox&#39;, &#39;dateFormat&#39;:&#39;dd/mm/YYYY&#39; ,&#39;useNewStyle&#39;:true} " 
data-role="datebox" id="mydate" 
name="From" type="text" value="29/08/2013 00:00:00" />
```

I know you can use html.raw - but how do you use it within a helper?

I need to show:

`{'mode':`

...instead of...

`{&#39;mode&#39;:`

Comment: The code you show as input does not produce the html you show as output. Was there a copy paste error? The `TextBoxFor` is lacking `mode` inside of `@data_options`.

Comment: you're correct - sorry, copy paste error - corrected above

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@Html.TextBoxFor(...).ToHtmlString()))`.

Comment: Note if you ever used `"` in an attribute this would destroy the tag.

Answer (score 3):

`TextBoxFor` uses `TagBuilder` which is ultimately responsible for turning `'` in to `&#39;` (since it uses `MergeAttributes` with the `htmlAttributes` parameter passed to the helper).

Instead of pasting the answer, check out [Stop the tag builder escaping single quotes ASP.NET MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924861/stop-the-tag-builder-escaping-single-quotes-asp-net-mvc-2)

Also, this isn't quite the same exact question, but then it is. I'll leave it up to others if they want to close it and cite the above reference.